# What's the best disassembly tool on win32 platform?

Tags: winapi, disassembly

I have a win32 software in which I want to do some modifications.

However, I don't have the source code, so I need to do disassembly first.

Could anyone recommend a good disassembly tool on win32 for me?

Comment: Recommendations for the "best" piece of software are off-topic here, as per the [FAQ].

Comment: @Cody, I have to disagree with that. For a start, it wasn't asking for the best (which _would_ be subjective and likely closed), it was asking for a good tool to do a specific programming task, no different to asking which sort algorithm to use for a certain arrangement of data. The FAQ states a question is okay if it "generally covers (1) a specific programming problem, (2) a software algorithm, (3) software tools commonly used by programmers, (4) practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" and I see this one covered by both parts (3) _and_ (4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always used [OllyDebug](http://www.ollydbg.de/) and, though my need for this sort of tool is not massive, it's never let me down.

Comment: +1: the fact that its free and has some awesome plugins makes it trump everything else anyways :D

Answer (score 5):

I'm biased, but for *disassembly* there's nothing better than [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/), in my opinion. You can try the [demo or freeware](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download.shtml) version and see for yourself.

Comment: I agree that IDA is the best, but when you take price into consideration it's a hard sell.

Comment: Maybe, but freeware version is often enough (people paid money for it several years ago after all), and if you do disassembly for living it pays off very quickly.